# JMeter - Using 8 instance but graph generates for only 1 instance

Tags: jmeter

We are using JMeter for performance testing. To generate 1000 user load we are using 8 instance(125 X 8 =1000) of JMeter. All works fine, but at the end of execution, graph generated is of first instance only. I want graph of all 8 instance. What can be done in this matter. Please help.

Comment: Do you use distributed mode for your 8 instances? Or just start all of them manually?

Comment: i use use distributed mode for 8 instances

Comment: i am sorry, All the 8 instances are opened manually and then the client (controller) machine starts the execution for all at the same time using RUN > REMOTE START ALL.

Comment: Ok, then you use distributed mode.

Next question to clarify: which graph do you use?

Comment: How do you know all 8 instances fired off? It sounds like only the master ran.

Comment: From aggregate report i can conclude that all 8 instance fired off. otherwise only 125 login samples would have fired. Main thing is, i am able to generate load of 1000 users but dont know how to plot graph for all instances. If you know any monitoring tool(open sourse) which can help, than please do let me know

Answer (score 1):

Option for GUI mode: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime

Option for non-GUI mode: http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/ConsoleStatusLogger

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Create a Simple Data Writer Sampler and save all your results out into one file.  After the test has finished, you can import that results file into ANY of the viewers in Jmeter.  This would give you a graph for the entire test.

You want to avoid having "real-time" viewers while running a load test (visual graphs, aggregate report, tree view, etc.) as they are very memory intensive.